# Executing PMCMD command from JAVA Client

Tags: java, bash, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I want to start workflow from JAVA. I connect to informatica server using SSH and execute the command pmcmd to start workflow

```
JSch js = new JSch();
        Session s = js.getSession("username", "host", 22);
        s.setPassword("password");
        Properties config = new Properties();
        config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        s.setConfig(config);
        s.connect();

        Channel c = s.openChannel("exec");
        ChannelExec ce = (ChannelExec) c;

        ce.setCommand("pmcmd startworkflow -sv integrationservice -d Domain_dwhetl -u user -p pass-usd hq -f dvl wf_test");
        //ce.setCommand("find -name PMCMD");
        ce.setErrStream(System.err);

        ce.connect();

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ce.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
          System.out.println(line);
        }

        ce.disconnect();
        s.disconnect();

        System.out.println("Exit code: " + ce.getExitStatus());
```

When I run this I'm getting the error : bash: pmcmd: command not found.
If I add path to pmcmd.exe:

```
  ce.setCommand("/PMRootDir/pmcmd startworkflow -sv integrationservice -d Domain_dwhetl -u user -p pass-usd hq -f dvl wf_test");
```

I get the error: /PMRootDir/pmcmd: error while loading shared libraries: libpmasrt.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

But when I run those commands in informatica server directly the workflow starts successfully.

Cand anyone help to solve this problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You have set the PATH to where Informatica is installed, or more specifically the directory the pmcmd executable is present.
Add the export command before calling pmcmd.

```
export PATH=<path Infa installation directory>:$PATH;
```

Answer (score 0):

@Samik, Thank you! 
I've added this

```
"export INFA_HOME=<path Infa installation directory>; " +
                    "export PM_HOME=<path Infa installation directory>; " +
                    "export PATH=$PATH:<path Infa installation directory>/server/bin; " +
                    "export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:<path Infa installation directory>/server/bin; "
```

and it worked

Answer (score 0):

You need to set Environment Variable Path 
**Example**

> export PATH=$PATH:/pwc/Informatica/10.2/server/bin 
>   export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/pwc/Informatica/10.2/server/bi